# Avoid overlapping of data points and provide tool tip for the same in advanced accessible highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Below are my questions

1. I am using advanced accessible chart in high charts and I have customized few data points to be circle . Since the data for these points is almost in the same range , it's causing the data points to overlap . How do I prevent this?
2. the tooltip provided for these customized data points(circle) are not showing up . How to get the tool tip displayed.

I have been pondering a lot but none of the solution is working . Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrdDG.png)

```html
 function DrawRemoteRequestPSRChart(seriesData, yAxisCategories) {
            Highcharts.seriesType('lowmedhigh', 'boxplot', {
                keys: ['low', 'high'],
            }, {
                drawPoints: function () {
                    var series = this;
                    this.points.forEach(function (point) {
                        var graphic = point.graphic,
                            verb = graphic ? 'animate' : 'attr',
                            shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs,
                            width = 0,
                            left = Math.floor(shapeArgs.x) + 0.5,
                            right = left + width,
                            crispX = left + Math.round(width / 2) + 0.5,
                            highPlot = Math.floor(point.highPlot) + 0.5,
                            lowPlot = Math.floor(point.lowPlot) +
                                0.5 - (point.low === 0 ? 1 : 0);
                        if (point.low == point.high) {
                            highPlot = lowPlot - 20;
                        }
                        else if (lowPlot - highPlot < 20) {
                            highPlot = lowPlot - 20;
                        }

                        if (point.isNull) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (!graphic) {
                            point.graphic = graphic = series.chart.renderer
                                .path('point')
                                .add(series.group);
                        } else {
                            console.log('graphic');
                        }

                        if (Math.floor(point.lowPlot) == Math.floor(point.highPlot)) {
                            graphic.attr({
                                stroke: "#FFCD11",
                                "stroke-width": 2,
                            });
                            //console.log('point.lowPlot & highplot ' + point.lowPlot, point.highPlot )
                        }
                        else {
                            graphic.attr({
                                stroke: "lime",
                                "stroke-width": 4,
                                "borderColor": "black"
                            });
                        }

                        graphic[verb]({
                            d: [
                                'M', left, highPlot,
                                'H', right,
                                'M', left, lowPlot,
                                'H', right,
                                'M', crispX, highPlot,
                                'V', lowPlot
                            ]
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
            var chart = Highcharts.chart('GraphHere', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'lowmedhigh',
                    inverted: true,

                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                }, legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    shared: false,
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.point.options.low != this.point.options.high) {
                            return this.point.category + ': <br>PSR Request Time: ' + new Date(this.point.options.low).toGMTString() +
                                ' <br>PSR Received Time: ' + new Date(this.point.options.high).toGMTString();
                        } else {
                            return this.point.category + ': <br>PSR Request Time: ' + new Date(this.point.options.low).toGMTString() +
                                ' <br>PSR Received Time: N/A';
                        }
                    },
                    pointFormatter: function () {
                        if (this.point.options.low != this.point.options.high) {
                            return this.point.category + ': <br>PSR Request Time: ' + new Date(this.point.options.low).toGMTString() +
                                ' <br>PSR Received Time: ' + new Date(this.point.options.high).toGMTString();
                        } else {
                            return this.point.category + ': <br>PSR Request Time: ' + new Date(this.point.options.low).toGMTString() +
                                ' <br>PSR Received Time: N/A';
                        }
                    }
                },

                xAxis: [{
                    categories: yAxisCategories,
                    crosshair: true,
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                }],

                yAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    gridLineWidth: 0
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointWidth: 10
                    },
                    series: {
                        stickyTracking: true,
                        whiskerWidth: 2,
                        grouping: true
                    }
                },
                series: seriesData
            });
            var seriesidexlength = chart.series.length;
            for (var seriesidex = 0; seriesidex < seriesidexlength; seriesidex++) {
                var dataindexlength = chart.series[seriesidex].data.length;
                for (var dataindex = 0; dataindex < dataindexlength; dataindex++) {
                    var fromdate = new Date(chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].low);
                    var todate = new Date(chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].high);
                    if (fromdate.getDate() == todate.getDate()) {
                        //if (chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].low == chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].high) {
                        if (chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].graphic != undefined) {
                            var obj = chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].graphic.renderer.symbol('circle', chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].plotX, chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].plotY, 5).attr({ fill: 'orange', pointwidth: 10 }).add(chart.series[seriesidex].group);
                            chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].graphic.destroy();
                            chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].graphic = obj;
                            //console.log("same date  -  " + chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].plotX, chart.series[seriesidex].data[dataindex].plotY)
                        } else {
                            //console.log("undefined"+seriesidex, dataindex)
                        }
                        //}
                    } else {
                        //console.log("not same" + seriesidex, dataindex)
                    }
                }
            }
            chart.container.onmousedown = null;
            chart.container.onclick = null;
            $('.highcharts-yaxis').hide();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, where the points are overlapping? Could you prepare a simplified demo of your case at the online code editor? That should help mi understand better, now I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus - pls find the below link . The points that are overlapping are the yellow points (circles)  https://jsfiddle.net/Vinay_10/vc8hrx6s/42/